# How do I load an SQLite database from file structure in a browser?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I recently started learning JavaScript by making a Pokemon battle simulator using the tutorial from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3wny3p/how_to_make_a_pokemon_battle_game_mini_course/) but I wanted to make it a step further by adding a database. I found one premade on [GitHub](https://github.com/danmane/PokemonSQLTutorial). My question is how do I load the database based on this [file structure](http://imgur.com/0H4cgfr)? I've tried using `sql.js` but to no success.

In my HTML file, I added the line `<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>` in order to get the `require` method to work for [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

Inside `main.js`, I have:

```
    var sqliteDatabase;

function loadBinaryFile(path, success) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var data = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        success(arr.join(""));
    };
    xhr.send();
}

require(['js/sql.js'], function (sql) {
    loadBinaryFile('db/pokedex.sqlite', function (data) {
        sqliteDatabase = new sql.Database(data);
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried with, it's easier to help when we know what the mistake is.

Comment: @miqdadamirali, I added the code

Comment: You don't need to convert it to string: [pass the UInt8Array directly](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/wiki/Load-a-database-from-the-server).